# Using SQL Server - is there a way to query 'Create view' SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to know if a certain table `dbo.person` is being used in any of the database views in my database. There are a lot of views in this database.

I could right click each view **"Script View as --> CREATE To"** to see the SQL that was used to build this view but this will take a long time.

I am wondering if there is any way to query all of these "create view as" scripts to see if any of them mention my table `dbo.person`.

I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the system catalog for views (and use `sql_modules` to get the view definition) then use the system view [`sys.sql_expression_dependencies`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb677315.aspx) to find which of these views reference `dbo.Person`:

```
SELECT  ViewName = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(v.[object_id])) + '.' + QUOTENAME(v.Name),
        m.[Definition]
FROM    sys.views AS v
        INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS m
            ON m.[object_id] = v.[object_id]
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS d
            WHERE   d.Referenced_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Person', 'U')
            AND     v.[object_id] = d.referencing_id
        )
ORDER BY ViewName;
```

There are [some small issues with `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`](https://sqlblog.org/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008), but I would still be more inclined to use this than to search for `'%person%'`, since this could bring back 10s, or 100s of extra results, any time a table that contains person (e.g. `dbo.PersonAddress`) is referenced, or `person` is used as an alias (`SELECT Forename + surname AS Person`) etc. It really depends whether you are looking for something that is going to be accurate most of the time, but may, on occasion miss a reference, or whether you need a catch all solution that will bring back extra results.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
where VIEW_DEFINITION like '%Person%'
```

You might need to change the WHERE to dbo.person or [Person]

Answer (score 1):

For a more detailed string search on SQL Server database object definitions please refer to [SQL Object Where Used List script](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/where-used-list-search-sql-database-objects-text.aspx)

You can simply call like

```
exec SearchInObjectsText 'name'
```

and it will return procedures, functions, views, etc where the text "name" is used

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer the question directly, but it answers the need. I use a third party add-in called SQLSearch from redgate. It's free and I'm not an employee, so this isn't a "plug" of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use this SQL to look in definitions. I didn't filter on `VIEWS` just in case it is used somewhere else.

```
SELECT
    so.name, so.type, sm.Definition
FROM
    sys.objects AS so INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS sm ON so.object_id = sm.object_id
WHERE
    sm.Definition LIKE N'%dbo.person%'
ORDER BY so.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Please query Information_Schema.View_Table system views

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE where TABLE_NAME = 'Emp'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.definition, o.name AS Object_Name,o.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_modules m
INNER JOIN sys.objects o
ON m.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like '%person%'
and type_desc = 'VIEW'
```